# MongoTimeoutException with Java. No changes before getting the issue

Tags: java, mongodb

I m facing with this issue:

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches com.mongodb.Mongo$4@11ad6cd. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=bastaproject-shard-00-01-vo5a5.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bastaproject-shard-00-00-vo5a5.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=bastaproject-shard-00-02-vo5a5.gcp.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:389)
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.selectServer(BaseCluster.java:108)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.getConnectedClusterDescription(Mongo.java:887)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.createClientSession(Mongo.java:877)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$3.getClientSession(Mongo.java:866)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$3.execute(Mongo.java:823)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.executeCount(MongoCollectionImpl.java:215)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.count(MongoCollectionImpl.java:183)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.count(MongoCollectionImpl.java:178)
    at basta.telegram.MongoDAO.subscribed(MongoDAO.java:31)
    at basta.telegram.BastaBot.onUpdateReceived(BastaBot.java:55)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:309)
```

I was able to connect with the database and get document's but now i cant. I did'nt change nothing at all in the code before getting this error.

Here is the code that i use to get the collections:

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = conexion.getDatabase().getCollection("users");
```

And here is the connect method:

```
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(
                    "mongodb+srv://cagide_j:"mypassword"@bastaproject-vo5a5.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
            this.mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
            this.database = mongoClient.getDatabase("bastaProject");
```

Comment: make sure your database server is running.

Comment: The server abruptly close the connection, check that your credentials are correct.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the server is running. The error persist.  Any news i will put it here.

Comment: assuming the computer where the program is failing has mongo shell installed you can test connectivity to the mongo instance in Atlas by issuing the following command `mongo "mongodb+srv://cagide_j:mypassword@bastaproject-vo5a5.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"` - of course you need to alter this command with the proper password.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that your Mongo database server is running and if Mongo is running on a different machine, as it appears to be, that you are connected to the internet. I'm not familiar with mongo.net, but many database as a service or in the cloud DB services have features that allow only IP addresses that are whitelisted to connect. I've seen issues with dynamic IP addresses that suddenly cannot connect. You could also try increasing the timeout.

It's hard to say much more without more complete code.

I often find that these issues are something simple, but not necessarily easy to find.

Comment: thanks for the reply. The ip is added to the list. And the server is running. Even so, I cannot solve the error. I think I'm going back to the previous steps to detect what the breaking point is.

Comment: gcp.mongodb.net is MongoDB Atlas product running on Google Cloud Platform.